# Perl - Concatenate non-empty strings

Tags: string, perl, if-statement, concatenation

I'm in need of a little help "optimizing" my code because I'm convinced there's a better, cleaner way to do it.  I have 6 variables that are created by being parsed out of a longer string:

```
Year
Make
Model
Color
ColorLower
Style
```

Depending on the record I may have details in some or all of these variables. In most cases, though, some are blank.  Following the variables being populated I add them into a database field that is the description of a car/vehicle.

Currently my if/else block goes one by one and if a variable has a non-zero length, the concatenated description variable

```
if (length($Year)>0)
{
    $Description == $Description + " " + Year
}
elsif (length($Make) > 0)
    $Description == $Description + " " + $Make
}   ...and so on
```

TMTOWTDI definitely applies here, and I always marvel at the elegant one-liners that the experts come up with.  Although what I have now is working, I'd be interested in hearing is there is a shorter, more compact way that I could maximize my code.

Thanks all.

Comment: There may be more than one way to do string concatenation, but using `+` is not one of those ways.

Comment: Nor is `==` the way to assign values.

Comment: You also have a logic error: only the first non-empty field will be appended to `$Description`, since you're using `elsif`. I assume this is just pseudo-code, though.

Comment: I'm a dope.. I'm bouncing back and forth between C# and Perl for this application and this week got the best of me.  I'm actually in C# for this, hence the colossal formatting mistakes.  Forgive me, guys... my apologies.

Comment: The real solution is of course to split those fields in the database. Storing concatenated values like that violates 1NF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
$desc = join ' ', grep { length $_ > 0 }
  $Year, $Make, $Model, $Color, $ColorLower, $Style;
```

Comment: `join ' ', grep length > 0, $Year, $Make, $Model, $Color, $ColorLower, $Style` will work as well.

Comment: Great solutions.. which I'll implement once I figure out what language I'm coding today.  I'm sure others will find the beauty in these one-liners.  Thanks!

Comment: There's no need for the `> 0` test.  Lengths can't be negative, and 0 is false in Perl.  `grep { length $_ }` would be more idiomatic.

Comment: @cjm: Good point so `join ' ', grep length, $Year, ...` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for the length test. An empty string is *false*, so this will work

```
$desc = join ' ', grep $_, $year, $make, $model, $color, $color_lower, $style;
```

It's also worth pointing out that capital letters are reserved for Perl global identifiers such as package names. Mixed-case identifiers are also particularly difficult for those who don't have English as their first language, and [*Wikipedia* has this to say](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)

> ***"At least one study found that readers can recognize snake case values more quickly than `CamelCase`"***

Comment: The string `0` is also false.  Based on the names, those variables are unlikely to be 0, but it's generally better to say `length` when that's what you mean.